# linear programming dual model

Tags: constraints, partitioning, linear-programming, integrity

I have a question about obtaining the sign of dual variables in the dual model of the set partitioning problem. As I know, when there is an equality constraint the dual variable corresponding to this constraint should be no restricted. Although, I found in an article a different interpretation, as shown by the following:

[Primal model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKOx9.png)
[Dual model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGR18.png)

I'm wondering why dual variables are restricted to be nonnegative?
Thanks a much for any explanations.

Best regards

Comment: In the primal model, the variables are restricted to be integral; is the dual model in fact the dual of the primal model's LP relaxation?

Comment: It might be possible to rewrite the partitioning constraints as covering constraints by assuming some big M values (haven't checked it though). Either way, this is sloppy writing. Can you share the original article?

Comment: Codor, in the article, the author said that the dual model is for that primal model, no comment about relaxation or even the obtained constraints. Loannis, yeah, here it is [link](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-07046-9_31) , please can you detail the method that you're suggesting, and if we rewrite the model, does simplex provide positives duals? I think not, so why we rewrite the dual model?